# Boost link error using Conan package manager

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log, conan

I encountered the following error while using the Conan version of Boost. The code compiles fine using the OS' libraries (albeit on another system).

Error output:

```
[  2%] Built target logging
[ ...] ....
[ 18%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/DEPTHFILE_UTILS
../lib/lib_logging.so: undefined reference to "boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert_impl(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, unsigned long, std::locale const&)"
../lib/lib_logging.so: undefined reference to "boost::log::v2_mt_posix::parse_error::throw_(char const*, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::attribute_name const&)"
../lib/lib_logging.so: undefined reference to "boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::consume(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/DEPTHFILE_UTILS.dir/build.make:146: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "bin/DEPTHFILE_UTILS" non riuscito
make[2]: *** [bin/DEPTHFILE_UTILS] Errore 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1018: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "src/CMakeFiles/DEPTHFILE_UTILS.dir/all" non riuscito
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/DEPTHFILE_UTILS.dir/all] Errore 2
Makefile:94: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "all" non riuscito
```

I already defined `BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` in my `logging.h` header, where I declare all my log-related macros. `lib_logging.so` is where the `init()` method is located.
CMake finds all the needed libraries and work fine.

Conan configuration:

```
[requires]
boost/1.66.0@conan/stable
gtest/1.8.1@bincrafters/stable
opencv/3.4.5@conan/stable

[generators]
cmake

[options]
boost:shared=True
```

Any help is appreciated.

System information:

- Running on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Conan version 1.13.0
- CXX Compiler GNU
- CXX Compiler version 5.4.0

Conan configuration:

```
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
compiler.version=5
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
```

Command run inside `build` directory (out of source build) using [this](https://bincrafters.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips_and_tricks.html) as reference:

```sh
virtualenv vconan -no-site-package
source vconan/bin/activate
pip install -upgrade pip
pip install conan
conan install ../
deactivate
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCONAN_BUILD=ON ..
make
```

Comment: Which OS are u using? Which compiler and version? Which processor arch? Which commands did you run? Which Conan version are you running?

Comment: thanks for reporting your own fix :+1:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the questions asked by @uilianries I realized my error:

```
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
```

This is [wrong](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/manage_gcc_abi.html).
In the installation command I added the following:

```
conan install --settings compiler.libcxx="libstdc++11" ../
```

You can also edit the default profile at `~/.conan/profiles/default` adjusting `compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11`.

Now everything works.